# Log4j2 Configuration Logs to File

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

I am new to Log4j2. I am trying to configure a logging system using slf4j and log4j2.

I have few doubts.

While configuring log4j2, I noticed configuration logs form log4j2 is printed in console. I want to print those logs in file instead of console.

Is there any way to use log4j2's appender .

PS : I noted that log4j2 uses StatusLogger to print its configuration logs. Is there any way to make it use a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to redirect the process output to a file:

```
java -cp lib/*.jar com.mypackage.MyClass > output.txt
```

There are some [properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties) you may be able to use to tell Log4j to write status logs to a file (probably `org.apache.logging.logj.simplelog.logFile`), but at best this will work after Log4j 2 is fully initialized. I assume you are interested in the internal status log statements that are emitted during Log4j 2 startup and initialization. For that, I'd recommend redirecting to a file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wrote a snippet like this, which will execute in static block of the main class

`final File logFile = new File("fileName");
logFile.createNewFile();
final StatusConsoleListener statusConsoleListener = new StatusConsoleListener(StatusLogger.getLogger().getLevel(), new PrintStream(logFile));
StatusLogger.getLogger().reset();  StatusLogger.getLogger().registerListener(statusConsoleListener);`